# new branch isn't showing up with git branch -a

Tags: git

I create a new branch with git checkout -b "branch_name"
I would expect to see this branch when I run git branch -a:
But I see no results, any ideas what could be causing this?

git version 2.36.1.windows.1

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might happen if you have no commits in the branch.

Comment: More exactly, if you have no commits _at all_.

Answer (score 3):

This is a completely empty repository; that is, it contains no commits. Therefore you are in the curious position of working with what is usually called an *unborn branch*. You are allowed to create the branch name so as to dictate what branch you *will* be on when you *do* create a commit. But until then, the branch is unborn and is not listed in your `git branch` output.